# How to create a new file in Sharepoint 2007 document library using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to create a Sharepoint doc library with my inhouse application (few HTML, xml, css, js and images all working together to create a cool website look and feel).

We do not have a server/host that can support PHP/MySQL or any sort of database functionlities...Only shared workspace available is sharepoint 2007. All the users will be on Internet Explorer 8. Maximum users 1000 but it is possible that they might access

All pages are static - view only information, However I do want to count how many times a particular HTML was accessed.

So I have this code that creates a new text file each time the page is opened.

It works perfectly ok on local folder, but if I put it on the sharepoint doc library it doesn't create a new file. It doesn't give error either.

Could you please help with this one or any other method using with I can collect the usage info - in future I wish to even have forms for collecting user comments/ratings which will be saved in such little text files.

code -

```
            <HTML xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
            <HEAD> 

            <SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 

            function WriteFile() 
            {
                var d = new Date();
                var n = d.getTime(); 
                var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
                var fh = fso.CreateTextFile(n, true); 
                // fh.WriteLine("Some text goes here..."); 
                fh.Close(); 
            }

            </SCRIPT>


            </HEAD>

            <BODY>
            <P>
            <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">  WriteFile(); </SCRIPT>
            </P>
            </BODY>
            </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a JavaScript API for Sharepoint with a createFile() function: http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.createFile

I think this function will help you.

Also to read a local file, you can either use ActiveX (as you did) or Flash (https://github.com/Aymkdn/FileToDataURI)

Comment: Looks like this will solve my problem...I have not had chance to test it in last few days. I will test it this week and let you know. thank you.

Comment: I have done, but the function doesn't run. No errors either. Debugger doesn't show any errors. could you please give me an example html page code to try? thank you for your help.

Comment: The documentation provides an example. I don't have a running Sharepoint available for the public (it's on our intranet), so no I cannot. But you can provide me your code somewhere and I4ll review it.